# Run custom sql query with Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I’m playing with Elixir&Ecto stuff. I’d like to create custom SQL query, which uses some postgres–specific powers (in this case: it searches postgres array).

Here’s what I’m trying to do:

```
iex(5)> query = from g in MyModel, where: "'sample_tag' = ANY(tags)", select: g    #Ecto.Query<from g in MyModel, where: "'sample_tag' = ANY(tags)", select: g>
iex(6)> Repo.all(query)                                                        [debug] SELECT g0."id", g0."name", g0."description", g0."image_file_name", g0."image_file_size", g0."image_updated_at", g0."image_content_type" FROM "my_model" AS g0 WHERE ('''sample_tag'' = ANY(tags)') [] (0.9ms)
```

unfortunaltely, it’s being escaped (so it should produce sth. like this: )

```
SELECT g0."id", g0."name", g0."description", g0."image_file_name", g0."image_file_size", g0."image_updated_at", g0."image_content_type" FROM "my_mode." AS g0 WHERE ('sample_tag' = ANY(tags))
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [fragments](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1) to send expressions to the DB:

```
from g in MyModel,
  where: fragment("? = ANY(?)", "sample_tag", g.tags)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can run sql via Ecto using

```
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(Repo, "sql here")
```

There is a third param, for prepared statements.

Comment: +1 Docs [here](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#query/4). The third param is an array for interpolated values. The example from the docs demonstrates best: 
`iex> Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(MyRepo, "SELECT $1::integer + $2", [40, 2])`
`%{rows: [{42}], num_rows: 1}`

Comment: To put things up to date, the `Ecto.Adapters.SQL` module has moved to the `ecto_sql` repository, so the updated docs can be found [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#query/4).